# Sum of infinite series pls

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I've looked at a lot of examples of infinite series, but I still don't get how to do this one.

$$-490\sum_{n=3}^∞ \left(\frac{-3}{7}\right)^n$$

Comment: Recall that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$.  Can you take it from here?

Comment: What is your difficulty ? is in the fact that sum starts from $3$?

Answer (score 3):

### Hint:

use the geometric series with $|x|<1$
$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}{\frac {1}{1-x}}&=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }x^{n}\\\end{aligned}}}=1+x+x^2+\sum _{n=3}^{\infty }x^{n}$$

Comment: False, take for example x=1. You have to specify that $|x|<1$

Comment: @Acuo95 I think you rushed too much to downvote. Look at the word "**Hint**" .

Comment: Yes, maybe i've been too hasty, i've remove it :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, no, you have not looked at a lot of examples, if you don't know one of the most famous ones: The [Geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).
I would suggest to look it up and then find out why you can apply it here. Hint: $|-3/7|<1$.